# How to use asp.net mvc EditorTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I read that EditorTemplates are loaded automatically, but from asp.net mvc 2 and now 3 with razor, I still cant get this to work.

My model looks like this:

```
public class RoleViewModel
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public bool InRole { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}

public class UserViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<RoleViewModel> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

My view looks like this:

**~/Views/Roles/Edit.cshtml**

```
@model Project.Web.ViewModel.UserViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Roles)
   <!-- Other stuff here -->
}
```

**~/Views/Roles/EditorTemplates/RoleViewModel.cshtml**

```
@model Project.Web.ViewModel.RoleViewModel
@foreach (var i in Model)
{
    <div>
    @i.RoleName
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => i.RoleId)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => i.InRole)
    </div>
}
```

If i move the content from the `EditorTemplate` to the actual page, then it works, it shows the checkbox, etc. But with this current setup, all that shows up is the count of the number of roles.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: right off the bat i think your `@model` is wrong in your RoleViewModel, shouldn't it be `@model IEnumerable<Project.Web.ViewModel.RoleViewModel>` - I think you also need to add a UIHint attribute to your Roles property [UIHint("RoleViewModel")] to help it find the right editor.

Comment: I tried the IEnumerable thing, I'm going to try the UIHint and come back.

Comment: Try it with `IEnumerable` because your code definitely needs a `List` model of some sort :)

Comment: @BuildStarted, this still doesn't show the template. same problem.

Comment: It works locally but the EditorTemplate is wrong...I'll post my working code as an answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### ~/Views/Roles/EditorTemplates/RoleViewModel.cshtml

```
@model MvcApplication16.Controllers.RoleViewModel
<div>
    @Model.RoleName
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RoleId)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.InRole)
</div>
```

#### ~/Views/Roles/Edit.cshtml

```
@model MvcApplication16.Controllers.UserViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Roles)
   <!-- Other stuff here -->
}
```

#### Models

```
public class UserViewModel {
    public User User { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<RoleViewModel> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class RoleViewModel {
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public bool InRole { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}

public class User {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit() {
    return View(
        new UserViewModel() {
            User = new User() { Name = "Test" },
            Roles = new List<RoleViewModel>() { 
                new RoleViewModel() { 
                    RoleId = 1, 
                    InRole = true, 
                    RoleName = "Test Role" }}
        });
}
```

The above code works just fine. Compare it with yours and see if you see anything amiss :)

Comment: This would show a checked checkbox with the name "Test Role"? Still nothing in my current project. Gonna try it in another project.